# advanced @Bean Spring plumb to resolve

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i got an advanced sprinf plumb issue to resolve..
in an application.properties, i got something like that..

```
      accounts.acbot1.name=acbot1
      accounts.acbot1.key=wB5-mFWRikey2vAbxWH0dvKPOU6dymVlxUwx4qWG

      accounts.acbot2.name=acbot2
      accounts.acbot2.key=IigkfCjUpGkw_NCFd-IjaNa2dj9wEwKEVmD_zVr2

      accounts.acbot3.name=acbot3
      accounts.acbot3.key=c6KhXgCnMbA_lqdR3zUmMCZFciaJsjo7xtZfRQej
```

and a pojo like that

```
    public class Account {
      String name ;
      String key  ;
    }
```

and a @ConfigurationProperties like that

```
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "accounts")
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Account> accounts() {
        return new TreeMap<>();
    }
```

All is well, Spring fills my Map.
But, now, i'd like to do some more advanced injections.

my pojo becomes

```
    public class Account {
      String name ;
      String key  ;
      Processor processor;
    }
```

i have @Component services like..

```
    @Component("service1") 
    class Service1 service1 implementing Processor {
      // some code 
    }

    @Component("service2")  
    class Service2 service2 implementing Processor {
      // some code 
    }

    @Component("service3") 
    class Service3 service3 implementing Processor {
      // some code 
    }
```

and i'd like my application.properties become something like that

```
    accounts.acbot1.name=acbot1
    accounts.acbot1.key=wB5-mFWRikey2vAbxWH0dvKPOU6dymVlxUwx4qWG
    accounts.acbot1.processor=service1 

    accounts.acbot2.name=acbot2
    accounts.acbot2.key=IigkfCjUpGkw_NCFd-IjaNa2dj9wEwKEVmD_zVr2
    accounts.acbot2.processor=service2

    accounts.acbot3.name=acbot3
    accounts.acbot3.key=c6KhXgCnMbA_lqdR3zUmMCZFciaJsjo7xtZfRQej
    accounts.acbot3.processor=service3
```

how could i do this, to link attribute 'processor' of 'acbot1' account to desired @Component named 'service1' ?

thanks by advance

Comment: Add your `Processor` class as well

Comment: @ray  it does not work. i got the message : No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.service.Processor]